# String Arrays and Session

Tags: arrays, string, jsp

I am dealing one serious problem and seems i cannot find a logical solution.
Here it goes.
I have a string array in my code (jsp file). I want to pass the array in the same page , and i thought of making the array a session and call it again  later in my code but it seems that i cannot take the session (with get.Attribute) and make it an array again. TO be more specise the following code might help you.

```
        while (onomaq.next()) {
                                    String onomatemp = onomaq.getString("one1");
                                    String[] onoma = onomatemp.split(" ");
                                    out.println(onoma[2]);
                                    session.setAttribute("onoma", onoma);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
                            }

                        %>

                        <%
try{
   Object o = session.getAttribute("onoma");
String k=o.toString();
String[] name=k.split(",");
out.println(name[1]);

}
catch (Exception e)
         {
                                                           System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
                            }
```

the out.println gives me a message lige [L.java.String and some characters.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: fix your post with some readable code...

Answer (score 3):

Rather than calling `toString()` on your array object after obtainig it from session, just cast the object reference to an array (since your object IS an array) and use it.

This means, replace this code:

```
Object o = session.getAttribute("onoma");
String k=o.toString();
String[] name=k.split(",");
```

with

```
String[] name= (String[]) session.getAttribute("onoma");
```

p.s. purpose of `toString()` is somwhat different from what you seem to expect. See [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] expected_array= (String[]) session.getAttribute("onoma");
```

Then run it inside a loop to retrieve. Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < expected_array. length; i++) 
{
     String strings = expected_array[i] ;
}
```